# @ngrx/reducer: createReducer(), and on() are not being type-safe?

Tags: angular, ngrx

When using previous versions of `ngrx` where I didn't use 
`createAction()` and `createReducer()`, it would throw an error if I try to add any additional attributes that were not part of the provided `State`.

I upgraded the app to `Angular 8`, and using `ngrx 8.3.0` as well. Now it seems like the type safety is not there anymore, even though `NGRX` documentation points out that most of the type inference will be implemented.

`someState.ts`

```
export interface ISampleState {
  id: number
}
```

`someAction.ts`

```
export const request = createAction('[SAMPLE] Request', props<{id: number}>();
```

`someReducer.ts`

```
const initialState: ISampleState = {
  id: null
}

const sampleReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(SampleActions.request, (state, { id }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      id,
      // Below would previously complain since only `id` is defined in the `ISampleState`
      thisShouldNormallyComplain: 'but it does not'
    }
  }
);

// AOT purposes
export function reducer(state: ISampleState | undefined, action: Action): ISampleState {
  return sampleReducer(state, action);
}
```

After actually running the code, I would see via `DevTools` that the store is indeed populated with this unwarranted attribute.

My biggest concern is when I have a typo in the reducer within the `return` block, it would also not complain.

i.e. If I accidentally type

```
return {
   ...state,
   Id: id  //should be `id`
}
```

it would be difficult to locate the error since it compiles just fine without complaints.

Any ideas?

Comment: Turns out this is a known issue from `TypeScript`'s end so you can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/241) for tracking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having played with this a bit, it seems like this is a problem with TypeScript! `createReducer` ultimately creates an `ActionReducer<S, A>` which has a signature of `(state: S | undefined, action: A) => S`.

In this case, TypeScript seems to allow any callable that satisfies this signature to satisfy the argument, even if the returned type has more properties than `S` does. I've filed [this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33908) against the compiler because to me that doesn't seem to be correct behaviour.