# NGRX reducer does not throw incorrect assignment error

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am working with ngrx for the first time. Normally in Typescript I get an incorrect assignment error for the following code because `other` is not specificed in the interface declaration:

```
interface IExample {
  count: number;
}

let initialState: IExample = { count: 0, other: '??????' };

// Type '{ count: number; other: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IExample'.
//   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'other' does not exist in type 'IExample'.
```

But when I am creating a reducer the `on` associator *(I think this is called an associator)* does not throw this exception and maps `other` onto the return object.

```
interface IExample{
  count: number;
}

let initialState: IExample = { count: 0 };

const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(add, (state, { payload }) => ({ 
    ...state,
    other: '??????' 
  })),
);
```

This is the `on` signature:

```
on<State, Creators extends readonly ActionCreator[]>(...args: [any, Creators, any, OnReducer<State extends infer S ? S : never, Creators>]): ReducerTypes<State, Creators>
```

How do I prevent these sorts of mistakes / how do I get these compilation errors showing again as they should ?

*Note: `"@ngrx/store": "^12.3.0"`,*

Comment: Seem to be TypeScript issue as described on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58309980/1283715)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the reducer `on` function, you see that it does not specify the return type. And Typsecript is probably unable to determine it on its own. You can specify it manually and this should underline the error:

```typescript
interface IExample{
  count: number;
}

let initialState: IExample = { count: 0 };

const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(add, (state, { payload }): IExample => ({ 
    ...state,
    other: '??????' //should be underlined now
  })),
);
```

But you have to do this for every single `on` function which is unfortunate. Hopefully this will be fixed on NgRx side. But when playing with this I found other cases which allows you to bypass Typescript check, `Object.assign` is on of them.

```typescript
const wrongIExample: IExample = Object.assign(initialState, { another: '????'});
// this is possible and does not throws error
```

Just to illustrate the fact that Typescript has its limitations still.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, and sadly this needs to be fixed in TypeScript.
As a workaround, you'll have to provide a return type to the on method.

```
const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(add, (state, { payload }): IExample => ({ 
    ...state,
    other: '??????' 
    ~~~~~~ error
  })),
);
```

Because it's a common issue, it has its own lint rule at
https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/on-function-explicit-return-type.md